# Populate localStorage once for a new user

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Working on a Chrome Extension that allows users to keep a list that uses localStorage.

Working so far: user can input things in their list and it will store in localStorage, user can delete things from the list and it disappears from localStorage.

Trying to figure out: how can I start the user with a few sample items on their list?

```
function startStorage (){
localStorage.setItem('list', 'your first list item');}
startStorage();
```

The above code's issue: every time the user refreshes the page it would populate the starting items again. Is there a way to populate only once? As of now, function fires everytime they reload so they get the starting items again.

Any thoughts are appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Use an if statement to check whether the storage already has the item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if this local storage item already exist or not with `getItem`

```
function startStorage (){
  if(!localStorage.getItem('list')){
  localStorage.setItem('list', 'your first list item')
   }
}
startStorage();
```